# WPF Xbap and WCF calls... do they have to be Async?

Tags: wpf, wcf, xbap

At my company we are writing a WPF xbap app running in full trust. I was wondering since it is running in a browser, I would assume the WCF calls that are used, have to run async. Is this correct? If it doesn't stop you from calling them async, is this just bad practice? I would also think it would be...

Thanks
harold

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing stopping you from writing synchronous web services in an XBAP app.

However, if you're making calls over the network, it's generally best to make the call asynchronous.